# How to iterate over HashMap<String, ArrayList<Record>> in Java?

Tags: java, generics, collections, hashmap

I want to access the Records I have created in the HashMap.
    Due to some requirements, I am unable to create a new data structure for holding my data.

```
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Record>> customerInfoTable = new 
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Record>>();
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: `for (List<Record> rs : customerInfoTable.values()) for (Record r : rs) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

1. getKeyList()    get key list, then for each get value
2. Iterator> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
   Map.Entry entry = it.next();}